# Discrete Lyapunov function candidate - How to find $dV(k)$?

Tags: derivatives, optimal-control, lyapunov-functions, adaptive-control

I have a discrete state space model as a desire reference model:

$$x_m(k+1) = A_m x_m(k) + B_m r(k)$$
$$y_m(k) = C_mx_m(k) + D_m r(k)$$

Then I have a discrete state model as real process model:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + B u(k)$$
$$y(k) = Cx(k) + D u(k)$$

And the adaption gain law is:
$$u(k) = (\theta^0 - \theta(k))Mr(k) - Lx(k)$$
$$L = (B_m^T B)^{-1}B_m^T(A - A_m)$$
$$M = (B_m^T B)^{-1}B_m^T B_m$$

Where $\theta^0 = 1$

I have an error:
$$e(k) = y_m(k) - y(k)$$

And I want $e(k) = 0$, which depends on $\theta(k)$. To solve this problem, I need to use the discrete Lyapunov function:

$$V(k) = \frac{1}{2} [ e^T(k) P e(k) + (\theta^0 - \theta(k) )^T ( \theta^0 - \theta(k) ) ], k = 0, 1,2,3,..., n$$

We can say that $\theta^0 - \theta(k)$ is $\phi(k)$

$$V(k) = \frac{1}{2} [ e^T(k) P e(k) + \phi^T(k) \phi(k) ], k = 0, 1,2,3,..., n$$

And $P$ is the solution to this discrete Lyapunov equation.

$$A_mPA_m^T  - P + Q = 0$$
$$ Q = Q^T > 0$$

**Question:**

I want to finding the derivative $dV(k)$ of $V(k)$ and then find the derivative of $\phi(k)$ so $dV(k) < 0$ will allways be negative as long $e(k) \neq 0$

**Edit:**

We say that $x_e(k) = x_m(k) - x(k)$ instead

Then we try to minimize the lyapunov candidate function

$$V(k) = \frac{1}{2} [ x_e^T(k) P x_e(k) + \phi^T(k) \phi(k) ]$$

The derivative of $V(k)$ is:

$$dV(k) = \frac{1}{2} [ x_e^T(k) P x_e(k) + \phi^T(k) \phi(k) ] - \frac{1}{2} [ x_e^T(k-1) P x_e(k-1) + \phi^T(k-1) \phi(k-1) ]$$

If we set $dV(k) = 0$, we can skip $\frac{1}{2}$.
$$dV(k) = [ x_e^T(k) P x_e(k) + \phi^T(k) \phi(k) ] - [ x_e^T(k-1) P x_e(k-1) + \phi^T(k-1) \phi(k-1) ] = 0$$

Comment: U (k) - U (k-1)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo My goal is to find when $dV(k) = 0$. To do that, I need to find the derivative of $\theta$ so $dV(k) = 0$ as long $e =/= 0$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Updated my question now.

Comment: In discrete-time models, you don't look at derivatives, but at differences. Hence the object you should start by creating is $V(k) - V(k-1)$. However, your setup makes no sense. The Lyapunov equation is for a function $x^T(k)Px(k)$, but you are using $P$ with $e(k)$ which doesn't necessarily even have the same dimension as $x(k)$ so the expression cannot even be formed.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I'm looking at Karl-Johan Åström's book Adaptive Control. The equations is not mine. It's from the book.

Comment: Where? This smells like MRAC/MRAS, and my version of Åström doesn't even talk about discrete-time MRAS as far as I can see, and when it does continuous time MRAS, it is not using e^TPe but x^TPx

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Yes. It's MRAC/MRAS. My version talk only about time continuous, but I want it to discrete because I'm going to implement it onto a microcontroller. Page 211.

Comment: So the claim that he uses $e^TPe$ in the Lyapunov function, where P satisfies standard (continuous or discrete-time) Lyapunov and $e$ is a function of $y$ is not correct then I hope, as it makes no sense.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I have changed my question now.

Comment: You still have the nonsensical  setup with $e^T P e$ where $e$ has the same dimension as $y$, and $P$ having size induced by the size of $x$.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Yes, but I have changed the question. Let's assume that it's the state vector error $x_e = x_m - x$ that MRAC want to use.

Comment: Why keep text and math describing something obviously wrong.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I don't know. I just read the book.

Comment: I simply don't believe you that it says in the book you have that you use a Lyapunov function involving $e^TPe$ where $P$ is defined from the standard stability Lyapunov function, and $e$ is constructed from the output $Cx$ where $C$ has arbitrary height. That's such an obvious error that it would not stay after all people reading that book.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg The author probably assume that the C matrix is an identity matrix? I assume that.